# List of objects, Fastest way to sort by key (one of its members) (complexity comparison)

Tags: c++, sorting, set, time-complexity

Given a list of objects in a container that can not be modified 
/* It's a map<>. sort order is based on 'name' */

```
struct Obj {
    // those and some other data is stored here
    string name;
    int key; // unique index
};
```

Need to get them ordered by the `key`. **Which way is faster?**

I can:

1. Insert them to std::**set** and then **iterate** over to get the order.

   *Per the C++ standard, iteration over the elements in an std::set proceeds in sorted order as determined by std::less or by the optional comparison predicate template argument.*
2. Or insert them to an **array**, std::vector, and **sort** it. (expected std sort is `O(n*log(n))` )
3. **Can you think if any other faster way?** In initial container they are sorted by `name`, which is irrelevant to the `key` index values.

Number of objects can be from 100 to 10000.

I think it is faster to use method `1`. Even though the analysis below (if correct) indicates they have same complexity of O(n*log(n)).

[Complexity](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-time-complexity-of-inserting-n-elements-in-an-initially-empty-balanced-binary-search-tree) of inserting N objects to a set:

```
log(1)+log(2)+log(3)+....+log(n)
=log(n!)
=O(n*log(n)-n + O(log(n)))
=O(n*log(n))
```

Comment: Use a [boost::bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: 10000 objects isn't all that many, and big-O analysis won't be particularly useful. The per-element overhead of inserting into a set is much higher than inserting into a vector. I'd guess that the vector would be faster, but the only way to know is to try it.

Comment: @PeteBecker on another side to sort vector you have to move objects around. I agree only test would answer.

Comment: @Slava -- good point. The thing is, a set does a sort on every insertion. It's a smaller sort, and moving elements just involves shuffling pointers, but the overhead isn't trivial.

Comment: Saying they are sorted by name in a map is a bit weird. That seems a better use case for a set...

Comment: Doesn't sort on vector<> copy objects around too?  And if I can use pointers instead of objects, can't  same be done with set<Obj*> with appropriate TCustomLess predicate for both situations?

Comment: @kfsone they are stored in this map and used a lot.(name is a key for a map in real situation).  But in this one case need to print by the order of their index (key).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, seems like an interesting read. Can't change the original map<> though to solve this problem.

Comment: @DoeJ. -- Yes, but for future consideration, if you must have data sorted by key and by data, and if memory requirements are not an issue (10000 items doesn't sound like a lot), then the bimap would be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the best solution to your problem is something like:

```
vector<set<Obj>::const_iterator> vec;
vec.reserve(set_of_obj.size());
insert into vector;
sort the vector using a custom comparator.
```

Some explanations:

- Sort set::const_iterator guarantees to be faster than sort Obj. Iterator is pointer based.
- Inserting to a vector and sort the vector guarantees to be faster than inserting into a set.
- Reserve the vector size ahead of time to avoid dynamic memory reallocations.